# After updating cucumber-groovy I get "Access to 'PickleStepTestStep' exceeds its access rights"

Tags: groovy, cucumber

After updating cucumber-groovy from version `4.7.1` to `6.1.2` I started getting an error `Access to 'PickleStepTestStep' exceeds its access rights`. In old version it was in `cucumber.api.PickleStepTestStep` and now in `io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep`

As I see `PickleStepTestStep` now is a private class.

How can I get the current step name now?

Example of how I use it:

```java
class ErrorLogger {

    List<String> errorHolder = new ArrayList<>()

    PickleStepTestStep currentStepDef

    int currentStepDefIndex = 0

    void setNewStepState(TestCase testCase) {
        List<PickleStepTestStep> stepDefs = testCase.getTestSteps().findAll { it instanceof PickleStepTestStep } as List<PickleStepTestStep>

        currentStepDef = stepDefs.get(currentStepDefIndex)
        newStep = true
        currentStepDefIndex++
    }

    private void addNewStepInfoToList() {
        errorHolder.add('############################################################')
        errorHolder.add('[ERROR] STEP NAME: ' + currentStepDef.getStepText())
        newStep = false
    }
}
```

The same problem I have with TestCase class.

The imports are as follows:

```
    cucumber_groovy          : "io.cucumber:cucumber-groovy:6.1.2",
    cucumber_junit           : "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.7.1",
    groovy                   : 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.5',
```

Comment: You'll want to use the classes/interfaces from the `cucumber-plugin` module. You can collect all steps with the `TestStepFinished` event. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/plugin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/plugin/event

Comment: @m-p-korstanje Where I can find info how can I use it and how can I get step name in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should only change used class from `cucumber.api.PickleStepTestStep` to interface from `cucumber-plugin`: `io.cucumber.plugin.event.PickleStepTestStep`

More information is here: https://medium.com/@cheparsky/migration-cucumber-older-version-4-to-newer-version-6-133ffb60813d